# Sharepoint 2010 Change User Active Directory Group Policy, Programmatically Add User to SharePoint Group

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, active-directory, group-policy

I have few Site Collections where permissions are granted using Active Directory Security Groups.

Therefore a Site Collection might have 3 Site Permission Groups which contains the AD Security Groups.

Now would it be possible to code a function within SharePoint to allow a single user to change the AD Security Group?

In the past I have used [this](http://www.mstechblogs.com/sharepoint/en/programmatically-add-user-to-sharepoint-group/) code for changing a single user to another account.

Also would I have problems with Synchronization with Active Directory doing it this way?

Please let me know If I’ve missed something.